# Cannot find symbol - variable answer

Tags: bluej, cannot-find-symbol

I have made this simple code which adds numbers together and finds the average. I get the error message shown in the title. The code below is; can someone please help me with the error when my tutor couldn't?

```
public class MathsQuiz {   

    public MathsQuiz(){
        int int1 = 45;
        int int2 = 56;
        int int3 = 34;
        int int4 = 89;
        int int5 = 4;
        int answer = 0;
     }

     public int add(int int1, int int2, int int3, int int4, int int5){
        int answer = ((int1 + int2 + int3 + int4)/int5);
        return answer;
     }

     public static final void main(String[] str){
        System.out.println ("MathsQuiz" + " " + answer);
        MathsQuiz mq = new MathsQuiz();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referencing a variable that you have not declared on this line:

```
System.out.println ("MathsQuiz" + " " + answer);
```

I presume you want to reference the variable you declared in the `add()` method. The simplest way to go around this is to call the method directly instead of referencing the variable. Like this:

```
  public static final void main(String[] str){
        MathsQuiz mq = new MathsQuiz();
        System.out.println ("MathsQuiz: sum of 1,2,3,4,5" + ":" + mq.add(1,2,3,4,5);
   }
```

Comment: Do some research next time before posting a question here.

Comment: ok i have done that and now it highlights this line and says 
            "int answer = ((int1 + int2 + int3 + int4)/int5);"
"java.lang.ArithmeticException:
/by zero"
and if i try to get rid of this line it messes up the rest of the code.
p.s. i did do some research i looked through my java book and asked my tutor neither able to help so i came here